# How to put a turtle's position in a table?

Tags: netlogo

I'm doing a school project in Netlogo for the first time.
I need to use a table that saves the turtle's position as key and a value. The especific turtle has a breed (pacman). I've tried:

```
set tbl table:make
set xx [xcor] of pacman 10
set yy [ycor] of pacman 10                  

table:put tbl [xx yy] 1
//(the value 1 is not important)
```

Why doesn't it work this way?
If I make:

```
table:put tbl [-2 -5] 1 //(-5 and -2 are the xcor e ycor of pacman 10)
```

it works. But the pacman changes its position so I need to save each position in the table.

Thank you

Comment: "Why doesn't it work" — you should really include the complete and exact text of the error you got when you tried it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new in netlogo and this is the first time I asked for help here. But your answer solved my problem. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/faq.html#listexpectedconstant says:

> If a list contains only constants, you can write it down just by putting square brackets around it, like `[1 2 3]`.
>
> If you want your list to contain items that may vary at runtime, the list cannot be written down directly. Instead, you build it using the `list` primitive.